# Sallam and salam - what is difference?

Tags: arabic

What is the difference between sallam and salam?

I have to write some more text, for this site's requirement:

What is their structure, construction?

What is difference in meanings?

I used to use and know only one word - salam, but I have seen "salallahu alayhi wa sallam" that means "may Allah honour him and grant him peace" (see [https://en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_be_upon_him_%28Islam%29) ). I used the word "salam" as "hello/hi". But both salam and sallam mean "peace" in the salawat. There also is salawat version with "salam": "ʿalayhi as-salām" (see the wikipedia article.)

Comment: Good Job, for asking that! Since it is seen that occasionally might some individuals make them mistake as they have relatively the same spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well both salam سَلَام (which is in first place a noun) or sallam سَلّم (which is a *verb*) have the same root مصدر or origin: سَلَمَ. I will try to explain most possible meanings and link some Qur'an Verses where they are used, hoping this would help to understand the meaning according to the context:

**[Salam سَلَام](http://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%B3%D9%8E%D9%84%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%85/) or السَّلاَم**

- could have different meanings among them: [peace](http://legacy.quran.com/5/16), [harmony](http://legacy.quran.com/6/127), freedom...
- but if it is in the context of [greeting](http://legacy.quran.com/4/94): it would be understood as [greeting](http://legacy.quran.com/10/10), [salutation](http://legacy.quran.com/14/23), salute which all is wishing peace.
- If it's in a context of peace after a war or to prevent a war: it could also be regarded as [agreement](http://legacy.quran.com/8/61) (well the verse linked use the clear word used for a treaty of peace) or contract etc.

**[sallam سَلّم](http://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%B3%D9%8E%D9%84%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%85/home.php?word=%D8%B3%D9%8E%D9%84%D9%91%D9%85&lang_name=ar-en&type_word=0&dspl=0):**

- also may mean: *to* greet,
- or *to* allow and [*to* grant](http://legacy.quran.com/33/56) if it's in the context of approving,
- it could also have the meaning [*to* save](http://legacy.quran.com/8/43) or *to* protect or *to* keep if it's in the context of an injury or accident...!
- Other meanings are *to* deliver or *to* give as [here](http://legacy.quran.com/2/233) (if it's for example a letter) or *to* agree and *to* accept.

Other examples:

- عليه السلام (alyhii as-Salam) which is translated peace be upon him: means also May the  Prayers and Blessings of Allah and his Malaika be upon him.
- صلی الله علیه و آله و سلم: All Prayers and Blessings of Allah be upon him and his relatives (family).

**Conclusion or general hint**

Briefly one could say that words of the root سَلَمَ like Salam/Salaam (noun)/*sallam* (verb)/Silm (noun)/*sallama* (verb) are in first place related with **peace**, words that are derivatives from Islam (Muslim (noun), *aslim* (verb)...) would be more related to **submission** and words that are derivatives of Salim/Saleem (noun) they would be more related to **sane** and **safe**!

And Allah knows best!

Comment: thank you. key phrase for me is that sallam is verb. i think it is good if you add also english translation so that sallam is translated with a verb, with somethng like "to protect",  "to keep or to set him in peaceful place".

Answer (score 1):

Concerning what you have inquired:

> Sallam and salam - what is difference?

Briefly speaking, **Sallam (سلم) looks often to be translated as "PEACE"**. e.g. as a famous phrase it is remarked: صلی الله علیه و آله و سلم، then it is translated as "**peace** be upon him and his household). Meanwhile, Sallam can be considered as a "Verb".

But the word **SALAM** can have some other meanings as well, especially it is used as a kind of greetings which means Hello. Among its meaning: Health, Peace, Hello ...

As well as this, Salam is deemed as a Name of Allah as well. On the other hand, it is considered as a "Noun"

Meanwhile, seemingly they have the same root of "سلم".

---

**Reference:**

- [www.almaany.com](http://www.almaany.com/fa/dict/ar-fa/%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85/)

Comment: have you added the phrase about sallam is verb after Medi Saif posted his answer, if yes, did you see/read his post, or not? this was key phrase for me to understand the difference, so i may select correct answer depending on who have written that first.

Comment: Uh-huh, God bless you for being fair. Actually I didn’t copy of his opinion and after…  (which is verb), I searched and finally perceived that I have not written it. But I think @Medi Saif wrote it before my edition. Since my edition was after his answer. Thus he is worthy of that. JazakAllah-Khaira for your attention.